# How to ignore Ctrl-A when a different escape sequence is already chosen

Tags: 11.10, byobu

With release 11.10, an old `byobu` setting I had from `screen` no longer works. I used to just add

```
esacpe ``
```

at the end of `~/.byobu/keybindings` to make the tickmark by escape for byobu key sequences.  That allowed me to free `Ctrl-a` to get the standard Readline / Bash / Emacs / ... emacs behaviour of jumping to the beginning of the line.

No more.  Now `byobu-ctrl-a` interjects, and I have not been able to figure out to the old behaviour (in essence: all defaults, but ` as escape sequence) back.

Hints, or better still, solutions, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set this up using [byobu-config](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man1/byobu-config.1.html). Just type that in the command line and select "Change escape sequence" and off you go. Admittedly it only allows you to set a `Ctrl-` sequence.

This does appear to edit `~/.byobu/keybindings` for you. I tried editing it by hand and it worked for me. The contents of mine with backtick working is:

```
source /usr/share/byobu/keybindings/screen-escape-keys
escape ``
register x "`"      #     | Goes with the F12 definition
register x "^A"
```

Comment: You're the man -- works here too.  Many thanks!